# Rewrite triple integral from Cartesian to cylindrical or spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How to rewrite this integral in either cylindrical or spherical coordinates? (whichever is easier).

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x \int_0^{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}} {(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}\over x^2+y^2+z^2}\,dz\,dy\,dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that cylindrical coordinates are going to be easier because of the limits of integration. In cylindrical coordinates $x=\rho \cos(\theta)$, $~x^2+y^2=\rho^2$ and $|J|=\rho$, where $|J|$ is the absolute value of the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of the change of coordinates application.

So, using just that you get the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{1/\cos(\theta)} \int_0^\rho \frac{\rho^{3}}{\rho^2+z^2} \rho~dz ~ d\rho ~d\theta $$

(If I didn't make a mistake calculating the limits of integration).

If you need a more detailed answer, please let me know and I will edit this post.

Comment: Looks like something is still wrong. Peculiar integral... Don't even understand why $\rho$ from 0  to 1 wouldn't work. Ah, it wouldn't work because then $z$ will be incorrect.

Comment: It doesn't work because in the XY plane you're integrating in $\mathcal{D}=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, 0 \le y \le x \le 1 \}$ which is a triangle. I also think that I understand what you think is wrong, when I wrote $cos^{-1}(\theta)$ I mean $1/cos(\theta)$, not $acos(\theta)$. I have changed it to make it clearer.